# Is there any python code from mysql that allows me to select the first row of observations?

Tags: python, mysql

I need to do a constraint for dates, with the "`BETWEEN start AND end`", and I want to set the default for both start and end. My problem is setting the default for start, as the first date of observations.

```
parser.add_argument('-s','--start_date',type=lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y%m%d').date(), help='Date of the beginning of the task', default= None)

parser.add_argument('-e','--end_date',type=lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y%m%d').date(), help='Date of the end of the task', default= None)
    (...)

query_dates = " AND taskdate BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s';" %(start_date, end_date)

if start_date is None:
        start_date = datetime.date.min() 

if end_date is None:
        end_date = datetime.date.today()
```

I expect the default of start_date to be the first observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm reading your question correctly, but it sounds like what you're asking is what is the SQL expression for the start date to be unbounded? You could simply use the expression `min(taskdate)` in your `BETWEEN` clause if start_date is `None`. That would equate to the earliest start_date.

Hopefully the SQL query compiler would optimise this, but a more efficient way to build the query would be to only use a `BETWEEN` clause when both start_date and end_date have been specifically set. For the cases when only either side is set, you can use a normal more or less than operators.

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer. My problem is writting down the min(taskdate) in python.

Comment: @MargaridaOliveira You are just generating a string for the query, so it's a question of only adding the quotes when passing in a date value. `query_dates = " AND taskdate BETWEEN %s AND %s;" % ("'%s'" % (start_date) if start_date else 'min(taskdate)', "'%s'" % (end_date) if end_date else 'today()')`

Comment: but if i want to set that constraint on the `if start_date is None: ', like i did with the end ?

Comment: @MargaridaOliveira I included all of that logic in my code snippet above, but I'm using native SQL functions as it would be more efficient. You could write it out longer form like you have done, but please note that query_dates has to come after your if-clauses otherwise none of that will work.

Comment: turns out that you were rigth! thanks for your contribution!